# Add data to ggvis tooltip that's contained in the input dataset but not directly in the vis

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

This is my input dataset:

```
> names(breakingbad.episodes)
[1] "season"           "episode"          "epnum"            "epid"             "title"           
[6] "url.trakt"        "firstaired.utc"   "id.tvdb"          "rating"           "votes"           
[11] "loved"            "hated"            "overview"         "firstaired.posix" "year"            
[16] "zrating.season"   "src"
```

For my `ggvis`, I'm using the following variables `firstaired.posix` and `rating`:

```
> str(breakingbad.episodes[c("firstaired.posix", "rating")])
'data.frame':   62 obs. of  2 variables:
$ firstaired.posix: POSIXct, format: "2008-01-21 02:00:00" "2008-01-28 02:00:00" "2008-02-  11 02:00:00" ...
$ rating          : num  87 85 84 84 83 90 87 85 88 83 ...
```

I successfully created my `ggvis` with a tooltip containing the `rating` information like this:

```
> breakingbad.episodes %>% 
ggvis(x = ~firstaired.posix, 
    y = ~rating, 
    fill = ~season) %>% 
layer_points() %>%
add_axis("x", title = "Airdate") %>%
add_axis("y", title = "Rating") %>%
add_legend("fill", title = "Season") %>%
add_tooltip(function(data){paste0("Rating: ", data$rating)}, "hover")
```

But I actually want the tooltip to contain more data, like the `epid` variable, so I tried:

```
…
add_tooltip(function(data){paste0("Rating: ", data$rating, "\n", "Epid: ", as.character(data$epid))}, "hover")
```

…Using `as.character()` because `epid` is an ordered factor – But the part of the tooltip is empty. (I also noticed the linebreak I intended `\n` to insert is missing, but that's a different problem).

It looks like the cause of this problem is that the `vis` object created by piping my dataset into `ggvis` doesn't contain the information I want to display, at least that's why I gathered by looking through the output of `str()` on the first example.

EDIT: I solved that linebreak issue, so there's no need to point me to `?add_tooltip` – totally forgot about that.

EDIT: The accepted answer is working fine, even though it doesn't let me put arbitrary variables in the tooltip, it's pretty much what I need for my usecase, thanks!
Here's what I did in the end:

```
breakingbad.episodes <- transform(breakingbad.episodes, id = paste0(epid, " - ", title))

breakingbad.episodes %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~firstaired.posix, 
      y = ~rating, 
      fill = ~season, 
      key := ~id) %>% 
  layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "Airdate") %>%
  add_axis("y", title = "Rating") %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Season") %>%
  add_tooltip(all_values, "click")
```

Comment: What happens if you put the `add_tooltip` before the `ggvis`?

Comment: Doesn't work, because `add_tooltip` takes a `vis` as its first argument, and that vis is generated by `ggvis()`.

Comment: you figure this out?  Key has to be unique.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Normally the client only sends back the columns of data that are actually in the plot. To get other columns, you should use a key to index into the original data: This is simple reproducible example

```
library(ggvis)
mtc <- mtcars
mtc$id <- 1:nrow(mtc)

all_values <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  row <- mtc[mtc$id == x$id, ]
  paste0(names(row), ": ", format(row), collapse = "<br />")
}

mtc %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, key := ~id) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
```

Comment: Thanks! I've chosen your answer as accepted because it covers the same solution as the previous answer, but also provides a simple reproducible example.

Comment: this is great. it would be even better if the tooltip would not be in a clunky serif font.

Comment: Is there any known drawback to this approach that is dependent on the type of plot? I have an example where i have a layer_lines() layer and a layer_points() layer. When I add the "key := ~id" input to the ggvis, it oddly makes the layer_lines() disappear from the plot. It is a somewhat complex example, so I don't have a reproducible piece of code yet, but figured I'd ask first if there were any known issues.

Comment: This approach does not work with `layer_bars()`. In that case it gives the following: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'id' not found`. Any idea what to do in that case? (E.g. you would like to plot the counts and tooltip the shares).

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to pass the epid variable in the `key` property, which is normally meant to keep track of which observations correspond to one another during transitions but it has the desired effect here of including epid in the data without producing any side effects:

```
breakingbad.episodes <- data.frame(firstaired.posix = as.POSIXct(c("2008-01-21 02:00:00", "2008-01-28 02:00:00")),
rating = c(87, 85), epid = as.factor(c(12,23)), season = as.factor(c(1,2)), somevar = c("special", "very_special"))

breakingbad.episodes %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~firstaired.posix, 
        y = ~rating, 
        fill = ~season, key := ~epid) %>% 
  layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "Airdate") %>%
  add_axis("y", title = "Rating") %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Season") %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data){paste0("Rating: ", data$rating, "\n", "Epid: ", as.character(data$epid))}, "hover")
```

If you needed to use multiple variable from the original dataset you can add an `id` column with a unique value for each row  and then do this:

```
breakingbad.episodes <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), firstaired.posix = as.POSIXct(c("2008-01-21 02:00:00", "2008-01-28 02:00:00")),
rating = c(87, 85), epid = as.factor(c(12,23)), season = as.factor(c(1,2)), somevar = c("special", "very_special"))

breakingbad.episodes %>% 
  ggvis(x = ~firstaired.posix, 
        y = ~rating, 
        fill = ~season, key := ~id) %>% 
  layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "Airdate") %>%
  add_axis("y", title = "Rating") %>%
  add_legend("fill", title = "Season") %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data){paste0("Rating: ", data$rating, "\n", "Epid: ",
as.character(breakingbad.episodes$epid[breakingbad.episodes$id == data$id]), "\n", 
"What this is: ", breakingbad.episodes$somevar[breakingbad.episodes$id == data$id])}, "hover")
```