# How to make ggvis tooltip interactive in shiny app?

Tags: r, tooltip, shiny, ggvis

In the example below, I have an interactive shiny ggvis choropleth with pop up label for income in each state. Users can switch data from drop down list.

My question is how to make the tooltip function interactive. The pop up label still displays the information of the original data set, even though user switches to the second data set. I tried to put it into reactive function and several other ways, but they all doesn't work. In the example below, I just use df1 in tooltip function to let you run and have a look at this app.

Thanks for your help!

Here is sample data

```
mapdata1<-data.frame(
  state=c("alabama","alaska","arizona","arkansas","california","colorado","connecticut","delaware","florida","georgia","hawaii","idaho","illinois","indiana","iowa","kansas","kentucky","louisiana","maine","maryland","massachusetts","michigan", "minnesota","mississippi","missouri","montana","nebraska","nevada","new hampshire","new jersey","new mexico","new york","north carolina","north dakota","ohio","oklahoma", "oregon","pennsylvania","rhode island","south carolina","south dakota","tennessee","texas","utah","vermont","virginia","washington","west virginia","wisconsin","wyoming"),
  income=runif(50,min=100,max=9000))

mapdata2<-data.frame(
  state=c("alabama","alaska","arizona","arkansas","california","colorado","connecticut","delaware","florida","georgia","hawaii","idaho","illinois","indiana","iowa","kansas","kentucky","louisiana","maine","maryland","massachusetts","michigan", "minnesota","mississippi","missouri","montana","nebraska","nevada","new hampshire","new jersey","new mexico","new york","north carolina","north dakota","ohio","oklahoma", "oregon","pennsylvania","rhode island","south carolina","south dakota","tennessee","texas","utah","vermont","virginia","washington","west virginia","wisconsin","wyoming"),
  income=runif(50,min=50,max=14000))
```

Server code

```
library(rgdal)   
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggvis)

tf    <- tempfile()
td    <- tempdir()
download.file(url,tf, mode="wb")  
unzip(tf, exdir=td)                

usa <- readOGR(dsn=td, layer="cb_2014_us_state_20m")
shp <- usa[(!usa$STUSPS %in% c("AK","HI")),] 

df<- fortify(shp)                    
df<- merge(df,cbind(id=rownames(shp@data),shp@data),by="id")   
df$state <- tolower(df$NAME)                                                  
df1<- merge(df,mapdata1,by="state")  
df1<- df1[order(df1$order),]

df2<- merge(df,mapdata2,by="state")  
df2<- df2[order(df2$order),]

shinyServer(
  function(input,output){

    dataInput<-reactive({
      switch(input$segment,
             "K 1"=df1,
             "K 2"=df2)
    })
###tooltip function    
    values = function(x){
      if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
      row = head(df1[df1$group == unique(x$group), ], 1)
      paste0("State: ", row$state,"<br />",
             "Income: ", row$income, "<br />")
    }
###choropleth
    vis<-reactive({
      data<-dataInput()
      data %>%
      group_by(group) %>%
      ggvis(~long, ~lat)  %>%
      hide_axis("x") %>% 
      hide_axis("y")%>%
      add_tooltip(values,"hover")%>%
      layer_paths(fill= ~income)
    })
    vis %>% bind_shiny("visplot")
  }
)
```

ui code

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             selectInput("segment",
                         "Choose segment:",
                         choices = c("K 1",
                                     "K 2")
             )
           )
    ),
    column(9,
           ggvisOutput("visplot")

    )
  )
))
```

UPDATED:

This is what I tried. I also use values() in add_tooltip instead of values. But it doesn't work.

```
###tooltip function    
    values<-reactive({
      data<-dataInput()
      if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
      row = head(data[data$group == unique(x$group), ], 1)
      paste0("State: ", row$state,"<br />",
             "Income: ", row$income, "<br />")
    })
```

Comment: Your `values` function arent wrapped in `reactive` function.

Comment: @amwill04 Thanks for replying. I tried to put it into reactive function. See my updated.

Comment: @aosmith Hi Smith! The tooltip works fine but I want it to be reactive. The problem is when I choose the second data set, the tooltip still displays the information of the first one.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959609/rstudio-shiny-ggvis-tooltip-on-mouse-hover specifically how they are not declaring the function before, but actually inside `add_tooltip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler `mtcars` example with a group-level tooltip like yours with `layer_paths` and grouping.  Both the graph and tooltip info change when a different dataset is selected.

ui

```
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Plotting slopes"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("segment", label = "Choose segment", choices = c("K 1", "K 2"))),

    mainPanel(ggvisOutput("plot"))
  )
))
```

server:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

mtcars$cyl = factor(mtcars$cyl)
df1 = subset(mtcars, am == 0)
df2 = subset(mtcars, am == 1)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    dataInput = reactive({
        switch(input$segment,
                     "K 1" = df1,
                     "K 2" = df2)
    })


    values = function(x){
        if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
        dat = dataInput()
        row = dat[dat$cyl %in% unique(x$cyl), ]
        paste0("Ave Weight: ", mean(row$wt),"<br />",
                     "Ave Carb: ", mean(row$carb), "<br />")
    }


    vis1 = reactive({
        dat = dataInput()
        dat %>%
            group_by(cyl) %>%
            ggvis(~mpg, ~wt)  %>%
            layer_paths(stroke = ~cyl, strokeOpacity := 0.3, 
                                    strokeWidth := 5) %>%
            add_tooltip(values, "hover")
    })
    vis1 %>% bind_shiny("plot")

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,Smith!

Comment: Smith, Do you have any good idea about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349513/r-how-to-change-plot-background-color-for-a-specific-range-in-ggvis-shiny-app/33353920#33353920