# R: How to change plot background color for a specific range in ggvis shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have a simple shiny app like below and you can run it. The plots are created by `ggvis` and user can choose student name from `inputSelect`. In the plots, I want to change the color of background in specific score range. For example, **in each plot**, the color of plot background for the score higher than 80 or lower than 50 are highlighted with blue(See picture attached). I was trying to add layers and draw rectangles onto plot using `layer_rects()`, but the problem is the values of x-axis are changed if different students are chosen.Anyone did this before or any ideas? And is it possible if I want only the points in that score range pop up? Thanks a lot!

[image: example pic]

```
  library(shiny)
    library(ggvis)

df <- data.frame(Student = c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c"),
                 year = c(seq(2001,2005,1),seq(2010,2014,1),seq(2012,2015,1)),
                 score = runif(14,min = 50,max = 100), stringsAsFactors=F)

ui = (fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("stu","Choose Student",
                  choice = unique(df$Student))
    ),
    mainPanel(ggvisOutput("plot"))
    )
  )
)

server = function(input,output,session){   
  
  dataInput = reactive({
    gg = df[which(df$Student == input$stu),]
  })
  
  vis = reactive({
    data = dataInput()
    data %>%
      ggvis(x = ~year, y = ~score) %>%
      scale_numeric("y",domain = c(40,120))%>%
      layer_lines()
  })
  
  vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Answer (score 1):

To have the width of the rectangles to change with the x-axis variable, you can use `x = ~min(year)` and `x2 = ~max(year)`.  I'm not sure how to make the variables dependent on the current scale limits, which seems like it would be a nicer solution.  But, this should work.  For example, the lower rectangle would be

```
layer_rects(x = ~min(year), x2 =~max(year),
            y = 40-3.5, y2 = 50, opacity := 0.05, fill := "blue")
```

It isn't vectorized for different limits (at least it didn't look to be), so you can write a function to simplify having multiple rectangles.  The whole server would look like

```
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){   

    dataInput = reactive({
        gg = df[which(df$Student == input$stu),]
    })

    buffer <- 3.5  # set to make the rectangle reach the scale boundaries
    rectLims <- list(lower=c(40-buffer, 80), upper=c(50, 120+buffer))
    make_rect <- function(vis, lims, buffer=buffer) {
        for (i in seq_along(lims$lower))
            vis <- layer_rects(vis, x = ~min(year), x2 =~max(year),
                        y = rectLims$lower[i], y2 = rectLims$upper[i],
                               opacity := 0.05, fill := "blue")
        vis
    }

    vis = reactive({
        data = dataInput()
        data %>%
          ggvis(x = ~year, y = ~score) %>%
          scale_numeric("y",domain = c(40,120)) %>%
          layer_points()%>%
          layer_lines() %>%
          make_rect(lims=rectLims)
    })

    vis %>% bind_shiny("plot")
})
```

For your second question, if you only want points to show up in that range, you can make a subset of the data to use for the `layer_points` or a logical vector (converted to numeric with `+`) and use that as the `opacity` argument,

```
vis = reactive({
    data = dataInput()

    ## Option 1: and use layer_points(data=inrange)
    ## inrange <- with(dataInput(), dataInput()[score >=80 | score <= 50,])

    ## Options 2, with opacity=~inrange
    inrange = +with(data, score >=80 | score <= 50)

    data %>%
      ggvis(x = ~year, y = ~score) %>%
      scale_numeric("y",domain = c(40,120)) %>%
      layer_points(opacity = ~inrange) %>%
      layer_lines() %>%
      make_rect(lims=rectLims)
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I run your code on my example data here, I found the opacity of color is changed when I switch to a different student. It is more obvious when run it on my real data, which is so wired.

Comment: For the second question, option 1 returns "Error in new_prop.default(x, property, scale, offset, mult, env, event,  : 
  Unknown input to prop: a200281.5897161024623". option 2 returns "Error : length(x) not equal to 1". I was trying to use function "which" instead of "with", it still doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: hmm, I don't know about the opacity changing for blue, that is mysterious.  For the second part, option 1 seems to work fine for me.  But option 2 is wrong, sorry about that, I will update it now.

Comment: Thanks! I like your idea though~

Comment: I am still struggling with the rectangle function.In this example, when I choose student c(has 4 points which is fewer than student a,b), the background color become lighter. If I run the function in my real data, it seems like the plot with more data points has darker color. No any background color if only one point. Do you have any suggestion to fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: I think it is strange, but do you even need opacity?  Try `fill="lightblue"` and move the rectangles before the lines and points.  I think it looks pretty nice and there doesn't seem to be any color issues.  `ggvis` is still pretty new and full of bugs.